# Polymer automatic node finding with dynamic id value

Tags: javascript, polymer

How can I access node that have dynamic id value using Polymer node finding by id?

For example

```
<template>
    <div id="{{ id }}"></div>
</template>
```

and in js

```
Polymer("my-element", {
    ready: function() {
        if (!this.id) {
            this.id = 'id' + (new Date()).getTime();
        }

        console.log(this.$.id); // this part needs to find my div element
    }
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's true that a JavaScript hash can be accessed using either dot `.` or array `[]` notation. If you have a literal name, you can use dot notation `this.$.some_id`. If you have an indirection, like `this.id = 'some_id'`, then you can use array notation `this.$[this.id]` to find the same value.

The tricky part is that Polymer only populates `$` array after first stamping the template, which happens before `ready`. If you had an external binding to `this.id`, `this.$.[this.id]` would work, but since you are setting `this.id` in `ready` it's too late for the `$` convenience.

In this case, you can instead query your shadowRoot directly:

`this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#' + this.id)`

Pro tip: at some point a subclass may supply a new template, in which case `this.shadowRoot` will point to the new shadow-root and not the superclass version. For this reason, it's best to install a named div you can query against, e.g. `this.$.id_div.querySelector('#' + this.id')`.

Comment: Maybe Polymer changed something in their updates but  this.$.[this.id] isn't working for me. The answer below works great though this.$[id]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$` like a hash:

```
id = 'computed_element_id';
this.$[id];
```

Comment: More detail would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Polymer provides a method to this ([source](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding)):

> For locating dynamically-created nodes in your element's local DOM, use the $$ method:
>
> `this.$$(selector)`
>
> `$$` returns the first node in the local DOM that matches selector.

In your case, this should work:

```
console.log(this.$$('#' + id));
```

Comment: According to this https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade `$$` is not avilable in polymer 2.x. Use `this.shadowRoot.querySelector `instead.

Answer (score 0):

> According to [this document](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade) in Polymer 2.x `$$` is not supported, so use
>   `this.shadowRoot.querySelector` instead.

```
console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#' + id));
```

*If you are using Polymer 1.x then you can use `$$`.*