# How to access any element within iterative templates

Tags: javascript, polymer

Consider the following polymer element.

```
<polymer-element name="some-element">
  <template>
    <div layout vertical center>
      <template repeat="{{item in array}}">
        <my-first-element on-some-event="{{handleEvent}}"></my-first-element>
        <my-second-element></my-second-element>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer('some-element', {
    handleEvent: function(event, detail, sender) {
      var second_element = sender.templateInstance.model.querySelector('my-second-element');
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I need to access `<my-second-element>` upon an event that was triggered by `<my-first-element>` within the same template instance. The `querySelector()` in the event handler obviously does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is woking example of your code: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wu3gVIAwZfW4KmSNraTF?p=preview)

Selecting is done by:

```
var second_element = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#second_element');
```

More explanation on Automatic node finding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588708/polymer-automatic-node-finding-with-dynamic-id-value).

Comment: Thanks for the effort! It *almost* works. The only problem is, that the `querySelector()` always picks the `<my-second-element>` instance of the first template iteration regardless of which button I've clicked in your example.

Comment: Well, that is called selecting by dynamic ID. Plunk is edited and now will do that job too.

Answer (score 1):

sender is a DOM Element, so you can use for example sender.nextElementSibling to get next node.