# Polymer - this.$[id] not working for dynamically-generated elements

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

### In Short:

In Polymer, I can't make `this.$[id]` work to query elements which have been dynamically generated, while `this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#"+id)` does the job without any problem. Why?

### In Details

What I have:

- A published array `elements`
- Another array `modifiedElements` which contains data based on the first one
- HTML blocks generated by `repeat` over the 2nd array

What I want:

1. Update `modifiedElements` whenever `elements` is changed (✓)
2. Update the HTML accordingly (✓)
3. Query the new blocks (for some interactions) (not quite ✓)

My Polymer elements:

```html
<polymer-element name="my-sorted-elements" attributes="elements">
    <template>
        <template repeat="{{el in modifiedElements}}">
            <div class="heading" on-click="{{toggle}}" target="collapse{{el.name}}">{{devices.name}}</div>
            <core-collapse id="collapse{{el.name}}">
                {{el.info}}
            </core-collapse>
        </template>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

... and its script:

```js
Polymer('my-element', {

    ready: function() {
        this.modifiedElements = [];
        this.modifyElements();
    },

    elementsChanged: function() {
        this.modifyElements();
    },

    modifyElements: function() {
        for (var e in this.elements) {
            el = this.elements[e];
            // ... do stuff on el ...
            this.modifiedElements.push(el);
        }
    },

    toggle: function(event, detail, sender) {
        // This works:
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#"+sender.attributes['target'].value).toggle();
        // This doesn't (not found):
        this.$[sender.attributes['target'].value].toggle();
    }
})
```

Any idea why the second method doesn't work in `toggle`? Should I somehow update `this.$`, or is there a better way to do the whole thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as designed. `this.$['id']` is not supposed to work on dynamically added elements for example when they are inside `<template repeate=...>`, `<template if=...>` or added imperatively.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and curating / My bad for not finding the other thread. Still kinda wondering about the best practice in such cases, but I will go for the "pro tip" of Scott Miles (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24589493/624547)...